# solve $\lim _{x\to 2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}-\sqrt{2x-1}}{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x^2+2x-4}}\right)$ without l'Hopital

Tags: limits

I came across this and I am struggling to solve it, without using L'Hopital:

$\lim _{x\to 2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}-\sqrt{2x-1}}{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x^2+2x-4}}\right)$

Any ideas?

Comment: Conjugation will do the trick.

Comment: @AndrewChin tried it, still getting $0/0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

As @AndrewChin has mentioned, one has that
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x^{2}-1} - \sqrt{2x-1} = \frac{(x^{2} - 1) - (2x-1)}{\sqrt{x^{2}-1}+\sqrt{2x-1}} = \frac{x^{2} - 2x}{\sqrt{x^{2}-1} + \sqrt{2x-1}}
\end{align*}
Similarly, we do also have that
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{x^{2} + 2x - 4} = \frac{(x+2) - (x^{2} + 2x - 4)}{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{x^{2} + 2x - 4}} = -\frac{x^{2} + x - 6}{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{x^{2} + 2x - 4}}
\end{align*}

Now notice that $x^{2} + x - 6 = (x - 2)(x + 3)$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: ah didn't think of factoring the polynomial... thanks!